# List of tuples, first tuple as key, grouping by key into into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, grouping

I have a list of tuples. The first part is an identifier that may or may not be repeated. I want to process this list into a dictionary, keyed by identifier. The problem, I've been unable to think around overwriting by key:

```
def response_items(self):
        ri = self.response_items_listing#(gets the list)          
        response_items = {}
        for k, g in groupby(ri, itemgetter(0)):
            x = list(g)
            l = [(xx[1],xx[2]) for xx in x]
            response_items[k] = l
        return response_items
```

e.g. A list like:

`[('123', 'abc', 'def'),('123', 'efg', 'hij'),('456', 'klm','nop')]`

will come back as

`{123:('efg', 'hij'), 456:('klm', 'nop')}`

but I need:

`{123:[('abc', 'def'),('efg', 'hij')], 456:('klm', 'nop')}`

I need to put in a step to merge/aggregate by key but I am not seeing it exactly atm.

What is a better or more efficient solution?

Comment: Yet another question about `defaultdict`?

Comment: `l = [xx[1:] for xx in x]` would be better. Also there is no reason to do `x = list(g)`.

Comment: is this your expected output?  or you want something like :`{123:('efg', 'hij','abc','def'), 456:('klm', 'nop')}`

Comment: Actually I want {123:[('efg', 'hij'),('abc','def')]} for k,v

Comment: If that is the answer, then yes 'Yet another question about defaultdict' but I'm not wholly familiar with defaultdict, and if I must, enlighten me.

Comment: Since the current code gives the expected answer, this is probably a better fit for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach would be

```
from collections import defaultdict

ri = [('123', 'abc', 'def'),('123', 'efg', 'hij'),('456', 'klm','nop')]
response_items = defaultdict(list)
for r in ri:
    response_items[r[0]].append(r[1:])
print response_items
```

which gives

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'123': [('abc', 'def'), ('efg', 'hij')],
                            '456': [('klm', 'nop')]})
```

If you want

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'123': ['abc', 'def', 'efg', 'hij'],
                            '456': ['klm', 'nop']})
```

as output, you can use `response_items[r[0]].extend(r[1:])`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `setdefault()`:

```
In [79]: dic={}
In [80]: for x in lis:
    dic.setdefault(x[0],[]).append(x[1:])
   ....:     
   ....:     

In [82]: dic
Out[82]: {'123': [('abc', 'def'), ('efg', 'hij')], '456': [('klm', 'nop')]}
```

Comment: This is really nice if you want to initialize the dict in one spot but want to continue to get KeyErrors for invalid keys after initialization.

Answer (score 1):

If there's some reason to be using `itertools.groupby`, then you can avoid using a `defaultdict` or `setdefault` methodology - [in fact, if you want to go down those routes, then you don't really need the groupby!] - by:

```
mydict = {}
for k, g in groupby(some_list, itemgetter(0)):
    mydict[k] = [el[1:] for el in g]
```